# Gem dependency issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let us say there are two gems

```
A ( depends on gem C version 2)
B ( depends on gem C version 1)
```

My rails application requires gem A, and B.

How do you handle the collision of two versions of the gem C while loading A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. RubyGems can *install* multiple versions of the same Gem, but it only can ever activate *one*. That's one of the reasons why Bundler was created: it will at least check for such an incompatibility *before* you run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly? I contact B's author and try to help them patch up to version 2 of C. I know that's not a good answer, but I've not found a way to use two different versions of the same gem in the same environment. And even if there were, I'm not sure it's sane to do so. :(